# drawing random image libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am learning java game development with libgdx and have the following issue.

I have a Rectangle array which I iterate through and draw an image according to the position of the rectangle.

My Questions is how do I draw a random image every render but still keep drawing the same random image until it leaves the screen. currently it is drawing the same image but I would like know how to draw a different pipe image every iter.

Thank you

My Iterator

```
 Iterator<Rectangle> upperIter = upperPipes.iterator();
      while(upperIter.hasNext()) {
         Rectangle upperpipe = upperIter.next();
         upperpipe.x -= 8 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
         if(upperpipe.x  < -32) upperIter.remove();
```

My draw method

```
public void drawPipes(){
    batch.begin();
       for(Rectangle upperPipe: Pipes.lowerPipes) {
           batch.draw(Assets.pipeImg, upperPipe.x, upperPipe.y,   upperPipe.width, upperPipe.height);
        batch.end();

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

I created a custom pipe class and just created an array of pipes, each new pipe object that went into the array took a random image.
I iterated through the array, and called the draw method on each pipe object.

Simple and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

One great way to get repeatable random data is to use a `Random` object (java.util.Random is suitable for game usage), and provide it with a non-random seed. Each time you put in the seed and request the same sequence of number types+ranges, you will get the same (psuedo-)random numbers. When you want different numbers, just change the seed.

As an example:

```
Random rand = new Random(1234);
System.out.println(rand.nextInt()); // an int from Integer.MIN to Integer.MAX
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(100)); // an int from 0 to 100
```

Will always output the following, every single time.

```
-1517918040
33
```

But change the seed (in the constructor for Random), and the output values will change. `rand.setSeed(seed)` will reset the Random to start its sequence over.

You could use this to produce the same set of random numbers over and over while the rect is on screen.

However, a more direct and simple way would be to to just generate one random number for each rect when it is created, and store that number until it leaves:

```
public void drawPipes(){

    for(int i = 0; i<Pipes.color.size; i++){
        num = Pipes.color.get(i);
    }

    for(Rectangle bottomPipe: Pipes.lowerPipes) {
        switch(num){
            case 0:
                batch.draw(Assets.redPipeImg, bottomPipe.x, bottomPipe.y, bottomPipe.width, bottomPipe.height);
                break;
            case 1:
                batch.draw(Assets.yellowPipeImg, bottomPipe.x, bottomPipe.y, bottomPipe.width, bottomPipe.height); 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue I am having is with keeping the old images drawn until the rectangle which the image is attached to leaves the screen

Comment: So you're not having an issue where the image changes every frame because it's picking a new random image every frame?

Comment: I apologies, it is exactly what the issue is, I did not fully understand your answer. can you give me written example so i can understand what you are referring to. thx

Comment: I tried using your second suggestion by creating a new int and placing it into an integer array every time I create a rect but my issue is the drawing. I am doing something wrong

Comment: You might be better off extending or wrapping `Rectangle` so that its index is stored with it instead of separately.

Comment: As far as drawing goes, I'm not sure where you are determining which frame in your sprite sheet to use for each pipe.

Comment: I tried using  textureWrapper but when I can the draw method It changes the images for all the visible images on the screen. see edited code